# Unable to render my error view with no layout in Phoenix/Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to render my error view without a layout:

```
defmodule MyApp.ErrorView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view

  def render("404.html", assigns) do # renders my_404.html.eex template
    render(__MODULE__, "my_404.html")
  end
```

And action:

```
def my_action(conn) do
  if something_wrong do
    conn
    |> put_status(404)
    |> render(MyApp.ErrorView, "404.html")


    # conn
    # |> put_status(404)
    # |> put_layout(false)
    # |> put_view(MyApp.ErrorView)
    # |> render("404.html")
```

But it doesn't work and it renders my main application template. When I uncomment the 2nd part of my code and comment out the 1st one, it'll hang forever and won't render anything.

Also I want to be able to set `layout false` in my **ErrorView**, because I don't want to have to call `put_layout(false)` from each action of all of my controllers.

Comment: `conn |> put_status(404) |> put_layout(false) |> render(MyApp.ErrorView, "404.html")`?

Comment: @Dogbert, I'll try that. But I want to be able to put layout (false) in my **ErrorView**, because I don't want to call `put_layout(false)` from each action. How can I do that?

Comment: @Dogbert, yes, it works, but I want this -- `I want to be able to put layout (false) in my ErrorView, because I don't want to call put_layout(false) from each action. How can I do that? ` also.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do would be to either:

- raise an exception that is already defined and has the `plug_status` field set to 404, e.g. `Ecto.NoResultsError`
- define your own exception module that does the same

  ```
  defmodule WhoopsyError do
    defexception [:message, :plug_status]

    def exception(_) do
      %__MODULE__{message: "Whoopsy!", plug_status: 404}
    end
  end
  ```

Phoenix will take over and render the error view for you without template.